# Mysql vs sql express server (HEX -> bigint and bigint -> HEX conversion)

Tags: mysql, sql-server, hex, sql-server-express, bigint

I am new to the SQL express server and trying to convert HEX to bigint and bigint to HEX again. However, I noticed that MySQL and SQL express server calculations give different results.

**HEX to bigint**:

**MySQL:**

```
SELECT CONV('DA346CC793AD1510',16,10);
```

Output:

```
15723311803489129744
```

**SQL Express** :

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), 'DA346CC793AD1510', 2) AS BIGINT);
```

Output:

```
-2723432270220421872
```

Why MySQL and SQL express servers give different outputs? From a mathematical point of view, it must be the same.

However, bigint to HEX conversion in both MySQL and the SQL express servers give the same result.

**MySQL**: `select conv(column_name,10,16);`

**SQL Express** `select FORMAT(column_name,'X');`

What is the right way in the SQL express server to convert HEX to bigint and bigint to HEX? Am I missing something?

Comment: When I executed the suggested query in the SQL express server then it throws an error: `CONV is not a recognized built-in function name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Why MySQL and SQL express servers give different outputs? From a mathematical point of view, it must be the same."

[BIGINT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) upper range is 2 to power 63 - 1:

```
 9,223,372,036,854,775,807   -- upper range of BIGINT
15,723,311,803,489,129,744   -- converted "DA346CC793AD1510" value
```

BIGINT cannot store such value and simply overflows:

`9,223,372,036,854,775,807 -> (overflow) -> starting from the lowest value (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808) + (15,723,311,803,489,129,744 - 9,223,372,036,854,775,807) -> -2,723,432,270,220,421,872`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how mysql stores the value? There should also be overflow in that case too. Is this true?

Comment: This is also the case with MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html. BIGINT upper range is 2 to power 63-1. Please feel free to correct me!

Comment: @SaurabhChauhan With MySQL you are using function [CONV](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_conv) which returns **string**- there is no explicit cast to BIGINT

Comment: I am storing result to bigint column in case of mysql. How can I achieve the same thing using SQL server?